# How to print a text that has a link in its content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can i print a content inside i want to put a link

i was trying this

```
setContent(`hi 
    ${(
      <Typography className={classes.link} onClick={showProfile}>
        ${him.first_name} ${him.last_name}
      </Typography>
    )}
    their car is ${him.car} 
    and house is ${him.house}`)
```

but i am getting this

```
hi [object Object] their car is 1 and house is 1
```

also i need to show breaking line like

```
hi [object Object]  
their car is 1  
and house is 1
```

i am rendering like this:

```
 <DialogContent>{content}</DialogContent>
```

Comment: Probably not a great idea to store JSX in state. State should be relatively simple. Objects(s) with `first_name`, `last_name`, `car`, `house` properties, and then have your JSX use that `Typography` component to render the state.

Comment: @Andy ok, can you post your answer, how could you solve my problem?

Comment: I don't have enough information. Can you produce a [mcve], or add your code to codesandbox.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you setContent using Template literals with mean it will be a string, not JSX

i suggest you to wrap it with `<div>` and dont use Template literals.

```
  const him = {
    first_name: "jon",
    last_name: "doe"
  };
  const [content, setContent] = useState(
    <div>
      hi 
      <Typography className={classes.link} onClick={showProfile}>
        ${him.first_name} ${him.last_name}
      </Typography>
      their car is ${him.car}
      and house is ${him.house}
    </div>
  );
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-f3qc3?file=/index.js

Comment: this part printed in two rows  hi 
      <Typography , i want to print in only one row

Comment: just wrap hi in typography
      ```<Typography className={classes.link} onClick={showProfile}>
        hi {him.first_name} {him.last_name}
      </Typography>```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule React state shouldn't be used to store HTML; it should take care of simple data structures that your React components will then render when the state is updated.

In this example I've created an array of objects, and added them to state. I also have a couple of other states - the first is to maintain the currently selected person, the other to change the visibility of the `Dialog` (I don't know which library - if any you're using - so I had to make my own.)

React iterates over the data to create a list of names. If you click on a name the `selected` state will be updated with that object from `data`, and the Dialog will appear. If you choose another name the dialog will simply update. If you click on the close button the dialog will hide.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const initialState = [
  { id: 1, firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Jones', car: 'Saab', house: '999 Letsbe Avenue' },
  { id: 2, firstName: 'Dave', lastName: 'Scott', car: 'Pinto', house: '12 Lake Lane' },
  { id: 3, firstName: 'Karen', lastName: 'Smith', car: 'Bicycle', house: '3 Joyless Terrace' }
];

function Example() {

  const [data, setData] = useState(initialState);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  
  // Get the id from the clicked name, `find` that
  // object in the data, and update the `selected` state with it.
  // Update the visibility of the dialog state.
  function handleClick(e) {
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;
    const person = data.find(person => person.id === +id);
    setSelected(person);
    setVisible(true);
  }
  
  // When the dialog button is clicked
  // hide the dialog
  function handleClose() {
    setVisible(false);
  }
  
  // `map` over the data and add the dialog
  // If a name is clicked on call `handleClick`.
  // `handleClick` will update the state and the
  // dialog will appear
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(person => {
        return (
          <div
            className="person"
            data-id={person.id}
            onClick={handleClick}
          >{person.firstName}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      {visible && (
        <Dialog
          person={selected}
          handleClose={handleClose}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
  
}

function Dialog({ person, handleClose }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>First Name: {person.firstName}</p>
        <p>Last Name: {person.lastName}</p>
        <p>Car: {person.car}</p>
        <p>House: {person.house}</p>
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleClose}>Close</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.visible { display: block; }
.person { padding: 0.3em; background-color: #efefef; margin-bottom: 0.2em; border: 1px solid #454545; }
.person:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: #dfdfdf; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```